# Do we need a tag for each punctuation mark?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need a tag for each punctuation mark when there is already the tag *punctuation*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, I see no harm in having separate tags also. It seems very few questions have more than two or three tags anyway, and this could help make searches more effective.

Comment: btw, I also don't see any harm, I am just not sure how it would make it more effective

Comment: I don't see any harm either. I think that using a different tag for each punctuation mark is less ideal. If somebody is interested in the use of the comma, and would looks for each question tagged with _comma_, he would miss the answer given for a question tagged with _semicolon_ where it is explained that in a specific case the comma should be used instead of the semicolon. IMO, it's not ideal to tag a question with _comma_ for the fact that one of the answers contains the word _comma_.

Answer (score 2):

From the use cases point of view, it seems unlikely someone would want a cloud of 'comma' related entries for polishing their skills with commas; or the dreaded colon v. semi-colon learning curve. However, as my poor skills of punctuation may show, I can imagine someone looking to improve their overall knowledge of punctuation and its usage.

As such, it seems to me that by consolidating specific marks in a 'punctuation' tag would be preferable to letting questions about individual marks hang out on the fringe with a useless tag. Obviously synonymizing (sp?) tags is another option, but if it's a black/white choice I find 'punctuation' to be more useful.

Comment: I'm assuming that both `[punctuation]` and any more specific tag would be applied to the same question. Otherwise, yes, that would tend break it up into fringe groups.

Comment: @mmyers: It seems that there are questions using a tag specific for the punctuation mark, but not the tag _punctuation_; see the questions tagged with [comma](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comma), for example.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: These things happen. Fortunately, we are free to fix those cases (2 of them currently wrt. `comma`) by adding the missing tag!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the tag is to be any use it is very good to have a tag for "semicolon" so that people can find out what questions have been asked about this and don't repeat the same questions.